# maybe adding a directory for the answered questions?

Tags: feature-request

it can be helpful for organizing the information...

Comment: search hasaccepted:1 to find questions with accepted answers.  answers:1 for questions with at least 1 answer

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Unanswered](https://diy.stackexchange.com/unanswered) tab to filter questions that don't have

- [any answers](https://diy.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers)
- [any up-voted answers](https://diy.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes)
- [no up-voted answers in your tags](https://diy.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=mytags)